# How to find a partial derivative in order to check whether the function is differentiable

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

I need to find out whether the following function is differentiable at the point $(0,0)$.
$$
f(x)=\sqrt[3]{1+|x|^{2/e}\cdot|y|^{3/\pi}}
$$
I think I need to find the partial derivatives first, but the problem is I am confused by modulus signs. Also, I don't really know how to find the following limit afterwards:
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}\frac{f(x,y)-f_x'-f_y'}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}
$$
in order to check whether the initial function is differentiable (this limit should equal $0$).
Again, because of the modulus signs.
Any help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the definition:
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(h,0)-f(0,0)}{h}
$$

$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(0,h)-f(0,0)}{h}
$$

Both limits are zero. The limit we now need to analyse is not the one you mentioned, it is

$$
\lim_{\substack{(x,y)\to (0,0)}} \dfrac{f(x,y)-f(0,0)-f'_x(0,0)x-f'_y(0,0)y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}.
$$

This limit is in fact zero and we conclude that $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$. In order to prove this just note that
$$
\left|\dfrac{\sqrt[3]{1+|x|^{2/e}|y|^{3/\pi}}-1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right|=\left|\frac{1+|x|^{2/e}|y|^{3/\pi}-1}{(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}((\cdots)^{2/3}+(\cdots)^{1/3}+1)}\right|\leq \dfrac{(x^2+y^2)^{\frac{2}{e}+\frac{3}{\pi}}}{(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}} \to 0
$$

Obs: In the first equality use the fact that $a-b=\frac{a^3-b^3}{a^2+ab+b^2}$.